# error while send batchRequests for batchUpdate in google docs with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, batch-request

I am trying to create a copy of Google doc file and replace the text in it using the methods `batchRequest, batchUpdate, replaceAllText`

As a library, I use the library `tanaike batchRequests`  from [github](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)

I can create copies, but when I try to replace the text I get an error `404`

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * переменная LIST получает данные с листа с названием 1 которые содержаться в 1 и 2 колонке
 * номер и фио
 */

const LIST = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName('1')
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues()
  .filter(f => f[0] != "")
  .map(f => [f[0], f[1]]);

function Creator() {
  var requests = LIST.map(([b1, a2], i) => {
    return {
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1IzwefpoJOksTyBo0CaGcsaG9L_jrZW6Vuw4lGqC07_Y/copy`,
      requestBody: {
        parents: ["1qI-T2m1sL_I69wc7EAOJr3ZK3233X5qX"], name: `Договор № ${b1} с ${a2}`} // заполните здесь название которое вам нужно что бы получилось
    }
  });
  var res = BatchRequest.EDo({
    batchPath: "batch/drive/v3",
    requests: requests,
  });
  console.log(res);
  batchUpdate(res);
}

function batchUpdate(res) {
  var IDS = res.map((item) => {
    return item.id;
  });
  var requests = support_lib.concatArrays(LIST,IDS).map(([num, name, id]) => {
    return {
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${id}:batchUpdate`,
      requestBody: {
        replaceAllText:
        {
          replaceText: num, containsText: { text: "<номер>", matchCase: true },
          replaceText: name, containsText: { text: "<фио>", matchCase: true }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  var response = BatchRequest.EDo({
    batchPath: "batch/drive/v3",
    requests: requests,
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
}
```

response:

```
17:08:00    Информация  [ { kind: 'drive#file',
    id: '1d11ss2B9tjQ_ZUZU6i58DdjT0pGzYcDDHs04BWkSirs',
    name: 'Договор № 1 с Кожевников Антон Юрьевич',
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' },
  { kind: 'drive#file',
    id: '1499DdvTuFzjSFFz8Fi-q9-_MSRUAGfVa36Nc9l1GQm0',
    name: 'Договор № 2 с Кожевникова Любвоь Алексеевна',
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' } ]
17:08:00    Информация  [
  {
    "error": {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "URL path: /v1/documents/1d11ss2B9tjQ_ZUZU6i58DdjT0pGzYcDDHs04BWkSirs:batchUpdate could not be resolved. Maybe there is an error parsing the batch item.",
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "URL path: /v1/documents/1d11ss2B9tjQ_ZUZU6i58DdjT0pGzYcDDHs04BWkSirs:batchUpdate could not be resolved. Maybe there is an error parsing the batch item.",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "notFound"
        }
      ],
      "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
  },
  {
    "error": {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "URL path: /v1/documents/1499DdvTuFzjSFFz8Fi-q9-_MSRUAGfVa36Nc9l1GQm0:batchUpdate could not be resolved. Maybe there is an error parsing the batch item.",
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "URL path: /v1/documents/1499DdvTuFzjSFFz8Fi-q9-_MSRUAGfVa36Nc9l1GQm0:batchUpdate could not be resolved. Maybe there is an error parsing the batch item.",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "notFound"
        }
      ],
      "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to that you are trying to use [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) with the batch request. In the current stage, this cannot be used with the batch request.
- In order to use [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) for several document IDs, it is required to use it in a loop.
- Also, your request body for Docs API is not correct.

Although I'm not sure about `support_lib.concatArrays(LIST,IDS)`, when it is supposed that `support_lib.concatArrays(LIST,IDS)` returns valid values, how about the following modification?

In this modification, the function `batchUpdate(res)` is modified.

#### Modified script:

This script uses Google Docs API. So, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function batchUpdate(res) {
  var IDS = res.map((item) => {
    return item.id;
  });
  support_lib.concatArrays(LIST, IDS).forEach(([num, name, id]) => {
    const requests = [
      { replaceAllText: { replaceText: num, containsText: { text: "<номер>", matchCase: false } } },
      { replaceAllText: { replaceText: name, containsText: { text: "<фио>", matchCase: false } } }
    ];
    const res = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, id);
    console.log(res);
    
    // Utilities.sleep(5000); // If there are a lot of IDs, this might be required to be used by adjusting the wait time.
  });
}
```

- When this script is run by supposing that the values of `IDS` and `support_lib.concatArrays(LIST, IDS)` are valid values, the copied template documents are updated by `requests`.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)